# no dns after boot for ~2 minutes

Tags: windows-7, networking, boot, dns

After boot I immediately got internet connection via wifi / router

```
C:\Users>ping 8.8.8.8
Ping wird ausgeführt für 8.8.8.8 mit 32 Bytes Daten:
Antwort von 8.8.8.8: Bytes=32 Zeit=11ms TTL=55
Antwort von 8.8.8.8: Bytes=32 Zeit=10ms TTL=55
Antwort von 8.8.8.8: Bytes=32 Zeit=11ms TTL=55
Antwort von 8.8.8.8: Bytes=32 Zeit=10ms TTL=55
```

DNS lookups fail shortly after boot

```
C:\Users>nslookup heise.de
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  62.117.1.25
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Zeitüberschreitung bei Anforderung an UnKnown.
```

~2 minutes after boot the DNS problem magically heals itself.

```
C:\Users\razor>nslookup heise.de
Server:  ns1.telecolumbus.net
Address:  62.117.1.25
Nicht autorisierende Antwort:
Name:    heise.de
Addresses:  2a02:2e0:3fe:1001:302::
          193.99.144.80
```

How can I fix it to have a working DNS resolution immediately after boot?

Comment: Instead of running "nslookup heise.de", run "nslookup heise.de ns1.telecolumbus.net".  Compare to "nslookup heise.de 8.8.8.8".  May also want to run "ipconfig /all" and check out any lines related to DNS server (likely) or DHCP server (less likely to be helpful)

Comment: the output of ipconfig /all does not change anymore. interestingly nslookup returns sometimes sucessful in the beginning, then returns sometimes, then returns not at all, and finally after ~2 minutes returns always. the behaviour does not change when giving another dns server (i.e. 8.8.8.8).
Pinging 8.8.8.8 succeeds all the time, see https://77177.de/dns-log.txt for the behaviour after boot.

Answer (score 1):

To help isolate the problem, use the [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) (Linux or OS X) command, which on a Microsoft Windows system is tracert. Issue the command when the DNS issue is occurring and when it is not. I.e., `tracert -d 62.117.1.25` to check the network path to the DNS server. That will show you all of the [network hops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hop_(networking)) between your system and the DNS server and, if there is a problem reaching the DNS server initially, where the problem is occurring. The "-d" option for tracert instructs it to not attempt to resolve IP addresses to domain names, which won't work initially. You can omit the `-d` option when DNS is working.

You could also, try changing the DNS server for the nslookup command when you run it immediately after boot to help isolate the problem. Since 8.8.8.8 is a Google DNS server, see what happens if you specify it be used. E.g.: `nslookup heise.de 8.8.8.8`. If you put an IP address of a DNS server at the end of the command, that DNS server will be used instead of the one Windows is configured to use. Alternatively, you can just type `nslookup` and then at the nslookup prompt type `server 8.8.8.8`. E.g.:

```
c:\>nslookup
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  ::1

> server 8.8.8.8
Default Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

> heise.de
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    heise.de
Addresses:  2a02:2e0:3fe:1001:302::
          193.99.144.80
```

If you use the Google DNS server initially, does the problem still occur or do you, instead, get a reply from that DNS server?

[I've used DNSQuerySniffer](http://support.moonpoint.com/reviews/software/windows/network/dns/DNSQuerySniffer/) created by Nir Sofer, which is free and available from his [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net) website along with many other free utilities he has created, for investigating DNS issues on Windows systems. You could use it to aid in troubleshooting the issue. E.g., you could use it to verify your system is sending out the DNS queries when the problem is occurring.

You could also test to see whether changing the timeout value for nslookup makes any difference. E.g., to change it from 2 seconds to 4 seconds you could get the nslookup prompt, by just typing `nslookup` at a command prompt without following it by an IP address or [fully qualified domain name (FQDN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) and then type `set timeout=4`. Another parameter you can adjust for nslookup is the number of retries, which can be changed with `set retry=X` where `X` is the number of times to retry. E.g.:

```
c:\>nslookup
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  ::1

> set timeout=4
> heise.de
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  ::1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    heise.de
Addresses:  2a02:2e0:3fe:1001:302::
          193.99.144.80

>
```

The change to a value, such as the timeout value, isn't permanent, it only applies to that instance of nslookup. Once you type `exit` to quit the nslookup command, the next time you use the command, you will have the default value of 2 seconds again.

**Update:** To determine if there is a network issue somewhere along the network path between your Windows system and the DNS server you are using, you could run some tracert tests, e.g., `tracert ns1.telecolumbus.net` or `tracert -d tracert ns1.telecolumbus.net` to forego DNS resolution for the tracert command. Tracert might show a problem somewhere else along the network path. E.g., you might see high [round-trip times (RTTs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_delay_time), or a consistent delay at a particular [network hop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hop_(networking)), etc.

You could also try changing the DNS server you are using to another one, e.g., the Google DNS server at 8.8.8.8, or use [OpenDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDNS) servers, e.g., 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220 - see [What are the pros and cons of using an alternative DNS instead of the ISP DNS server?](https://superuser.com/questions/424934/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-an-alternative-dns-instead-of-the-isp-dns-se). You could make the change at the Windows system itself; if it is obtaining an IP address via DHCP now, you could modify the configuration of the network adapter on the Windows system to use a static IP address and DNS server, instead or, if your router is functioning as a DHCP server, you could configure your router to provide a Google or OpenDNS DNS server IP address for the DNS server that devices on your local area network (LAN) will use. Then check to see if the problem remains or no longer exists.

Comment: I can ping 8.8.8.8 all the time sucessfully. However after boot some dns lookups suceed, some not, then there is a time of ~1 minute without any sucess, until finally it works always. see also https://77177.de/dns-log.txt

Comment: @edlerd, I updated my post to include information about a utility I use on Windows systems for troubleshooting DNS problems and also some parameters you can adjust within nslookup, e.g., the timeout value, to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! DNSQuerySniffer shows just a "yellow bubble" for timeout. With it I just realized: also long after boot, there are still some DNS requests with timeouts.
When setting the timeout in nslookup to 4s, every request is responded (max 1 attempt fails, the 2nd _always_ succeeds).

Comment: I could reproduce occasional timeouts on another host in the same network. There seem to be more timeouts, when more requests are made in the same time. Maybe the router has a problem? How could I verify this?

Comment: @edlerd, there could be a problem at your router or it could be beyond your router at some intervening router between your router and the ns1.telecolumbus.net DNS server or the problem could even be at that DNS server or even on your Windows system, itself. I've updated my post with some further troubleshooting steps you might take to help narrow down the possible source of the problem.

Comment: I contacted my provider regarding the problems. The issue is gone now (even though I got no feedback from the provider yet).